# Is it possible to force Riak 2.0 to re-index data after changing a schema, without reloading the data?

Tags: solr, riak, riak-search

I have a Riak Search index of about 5 million docs that I would like to experiment with making changes to the schema. Is it possible to have Riak re-index that data without having to insert those documents again?

Does this happen automatically when the schema is changed?

I could not find information about this in the docs.

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: I found this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.riak.user/14727

It is helpful info, but it is several months old so the question is still open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the only way to re-index the objects is to iterate over each of the keys and update the object to trigger an update to the index. There are improvements in the works that should address this common use case in an upcoming release:

https://github.com/basho/yokozuna/pull/439

https://github.com/basho/yokozuna/pull/427